# Is this photo at all fixable in any program?

Tags: photo-editing

I don't know anything about graphic design but I would really like to know if there is any possible way to fix this photo.
I understand this is probably beyond unfix-able but I'd like to know if there's any way.
This one is the original:[image: Original]

This I tried to fix myself in Paint.net.
[image]

Comment: Can you describe what "fixable" means to you?

Comment: Hi OP and @JeeterFan. Do you have two accounts, or is something else going on? If you accidentally created a duplicate account, please take a look at [how to merge two accounts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 2):

If by fixable, you mean that you want to see the silhouette of the person more clearly (less back-lit), then I think the method I would use if I was editing this image would be to change the contrast, exposure, lighting in Adobe Photoshop using the filters, then masking them to preserve the beautiful contrast of the background.

This is a pretty good tutorial that shows Brightness in [action](https://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/adding-a-brightness-contrast-adjustment-layer-in-photoshop/). If you want a really natural looking transition between the person and background after applying the filters, you can use Apply Image under the Image tab to apply the original image to the mask (you can invert it for a different effect depending on your needs-keyboard shortcut is <kbd>CTRL+I</kbd>.

Another method is to double click on the mask and select a colour range that you want hidden from the filters (it should appear in the menu when you double-click).

It's a lot of playing around with brushes on the masks and filters to see what you fancy most.

This [link](https://layersmagazine.com/fixing-backlit-photos.html) shows a brief description of other techniques you can use in Photoshop Lightroom.

A free alternative to Photoshop is to use [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/). I have heard many good things about the program. Though I can't give any advice on it since I don't use it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to fix this image in Adobe Photoshop, you could select the person and adjust the levels, you could adjust brightness and contrast or play around with the camera raw filter controls.

You can Create an account on the [Adobe Creative Cloud](https://www.adobe.com/creativecloud.html) and pay for a month's membership for $9.99CAD a month.

There's many tutorials online for beginners. I recommend [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lq3Z4DaxHOc).

If you don't want to install any software, most phones have a filter feature that might help but probably not a perfect result.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are lots of ways to "fix" this photo, whether in GIMP (freeware) Adobe Photoshop, Affinity Designer or other such tools - for this one, Lightroom would probably work.

I took a couple quick minutes in Affinity Photo and selected the figure area, ran some adjustment filters and came up with measurable improvement, but the base photo is not great to begin with, as I'm sure you're aware: it *is* possible to shoot good backlit photos, but it takes some skill and careful setup and awareness of lighting and white balance, none of which occur in this image.

As a precaution against this space becoming a "work upon request" venue, I added a big watermark, so that you can't easily *use* this result, it's just to clearly demonstrate that with the expenditure of 120 seconds in Affinity Photo I was able to get reasonable improvements - with more time and thought, whether in Photoshop, Affinity Photo, Lightroom, GIMP - I think the clear answer is yes, if you take the time to learn a little bit about photo editing software, make a choice and work with one of them, you can get a lot of improvement.

[image]

[image]